# Tooltip fade out delay in OS X 10.11.1 and Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: xcode, macos

Does anyone know where I can set the delay/time how long does the fade out effect in Xcode 7.1.1 on OS X 10.11.1 need to hide the displayed tooltip?

When I search for the term `defaults find tooltip`, I only get `WebKitShowsToolTipOverTruncatedText` and `WebKit2ShowsToolTipOverTruncatedText` from *com.apple.iTunes* and *com.apple.appstore*.

With `defaults find delay` I get more results, but nothing about I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up via Apple Terminal. For example:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 5000
```

The value of `delay` is measured in milliseconds. So `5000 ms` == `5 sec`.

To find changed `NextStep ToolTipDelay` values in definite domains use:

```
defaults find NSInitialToolTipDelay
```

Comment: not working for me in Xcode 11. Is there a way to disable the tooltips completely? They are stupid and provide no information at all.

Comment: `NSInitialToolTipDelay` is the time to appear.  The OP is asking for the time to disappear.