# How can I manage hover tooltips and their delays on macOS?

Tags: mouse, icon

It seems many first-party programs in macOS either have no tooltips at all or the delay is uncomfortably long. This combination often leaves me hovering my cursor over a button with an icon and no text for a second or more like a goober. [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329272/320907) they mention a way to change it "globally" but the question was about Xcode. I'm asking about *all* macOS programs, or at least the Apple ones. I'm currently using Firefox and things seem to work as I'd expect. Most icons have tooltips and they come up pretty quick.

For an example of this I take a screenshot with Cmd + Shift + 5 and then click the image to edit it. I see four icons in the upper right corner.

[image: Four unlabeled icons with no tooltip on hover]

What the heck are these? I assume the trashcan deletes it, and I can make a safe guess that the second one edits it because it looks sort of like a pen, but there's no tooltips on these when I hover. It's hard to think of examples but I've noticed this a lot.

Is there any way to turn on tooltips or labels for buttons? Searching the preferences I see something for hover text but that's for making text larger to read.

Comment: Tooltips in *applications* that are not first party apps (EG made by Apple) are completely up to the developer. They can implement them or not at their choosing. Presumably this includes the hover time before getting a tooltip. In your example the "*I*" likely means *information*, the pen may mean *edit* or draw, depending on the app. The trash can *"delete"* and the box with the arrow *"share*." You can always contact the developer with your concerns.

Comment: This [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/uz6tv4/macos_124_has_restored_the_tooltip_delay/?rdt=50695) suggests there's a default you can override - but whether a specific app will use it or not who knows..

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for your comment, I have edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

idk If this still works but there is a command for terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 100
```

can be adjusted as needed just know that there are preset minimums. in previous macOS I believe there was a 2-3 delay, and developers can add there own on top of this. maybe they combine and that is why its so long.. not sure.

Comment: What is the value, milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, also this post also elaborates more on the topic     
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215362/tooltip-fade-out-delay-in-os-x-10-11-1-and-xcode-7-1-1/288926#288926